# Downloading file in JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am very new to JSP and please don’t blame me if my question is too dumb. I am trying to download a file with definite size say some 2KB in xyz.jsp and trying to calculate the time taken for downloading it. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer isn't going to be too specific, but generally here is what you'll need:

1.) Some sort of listener that can detect when the download of your file begins, as well as detect when the download ends. This might depend on the type of file you are downloading.

2.) You can insert some JSP scriplets to declare a start time variable and another one for when the download ends. Like this:

```
// When the download starts (detected by listener)
   <% long startTime = System.nanoTime(); %>

...downloads here...

// When it finshes (detected by listener)
   <% long totalTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime; %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ya I hope this will help me, if I am stuck somewhere I will get back.